# Why does this UPDATE affect 2 rows when its WHERE specifies only one?

Tags: mysql, sql, random, sql-update, sql-order-by

Please examine the following UPDATE statement that I'm running in MySQL 8.0, against the [Sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) sample database:

```
UPDATE `film`
SET
    `original_language_id` = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 6))
WHERE
    `film_id` = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 1000));
```

The idea is to update a random row from `film` to have the `original_language_id` column key for that row have a value between 1 and 6.

The `film` table has 1000 rows in it with PKs from 1 to 1000. The `original_language_id` column is a foreign key to the `language` table. The `language` table has 6 rows in it with PKs from 1 to 6.

The above UPDATE statement is deemed unsafe by MySQL (Error 1175). (I'd love to know why, but that's not my question). So to force the statement to run, I precede it with: `SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;`.

When I then run the UPDATE statement I expect to see in the Output window:

> 1 row(s) affected Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

But instead I sometimes get 0 rows affected, sometimes 1 and sometimes 2!

**My question is** why doesn't this UPDATE statement consistently affect one and only one row?

*PS - Please avoid comments on whether the query makes sense to you or not and/or on the prudence of disabling safe update mode. The query is an exercise for learning purposes and I'm fully aware of the importance of said mode. Thank you.*

Comment: _"I'd love to know why, but that's not my question"_ The software warned you that the query was unsafe, but you deliberately ignored it and overrode the warning. Then you got unexpected results, and wonder why? You should focus on the warning!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE `film_id` = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 1000))
```

is executed for each row of the table and each time a **new** random number is generated and checked against the value of the column `film_id`.
So it happens sometimes that the 2 numbers are equal, it can be 1,2 or many rows or even none.

If you want to update only 1 random row you can join a query that returns 1 random number like this:

```
UPDATE `film` f
INNER JOIN (SELECT FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 1000)) rnd) t
ON t.rnd = f.`film_id`
SET `original_language_id` = FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 6))
```

Comment: Mind. Blown. Do you perhaps know a link to documentation? Does this also apply to SQL Server?

Comment: As far as I know this is SQL standard.

Comment: *"where_condition is an expression that evaluates to true for each row to be selected"* (source: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: and would you know why MySQL classifies the statement as unsafe?

Comment: I assume this is because you are updating random rows and this is considered unsafe because it could update all the rows of the table.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pick a random row for update, then you can simply use `order by rand()` and `limit 1`:

```
update film
set original_language_id = floor(1 + (rand() * 6))
order by rand()
limit 1
```

This should be more efficient than other solutions using a join - and it works regardless of the number of rows in the table (while your original approach requests that you know how many rows there are in the table before hand)